# How is the probability of intersystem crossing influenced by small differences in energy levels?

Tags: photons, absorption

Say I have some dye molecule in some low level triplet state, e.g. $T_1$, and it's decaying slowly to the ground state via phosphorescence.  However, there are also events where the dye in the $T_1$ state can undergo intersystem crossing to transition to the first singlet excited state, $S_1$, which then decays rapidly to the ground state releasing a photon in the process.

Predicting the probability of intersystem crossing is difficult, and usually requires experimental support.  So I'm not asking here about how to *ab initio* calculate this probability.  What I'm interested in is how the probability changes as a function of what we'll call $\Delta G$, which is the difference in energy between the $T_1$ and $S_1$ state.

Can we understand the influence of the energy gap on the probability of $T_1 \to S_1$ intersystem crossing using a simple Boltzmann approximation of the form: $P(T_1 \to S_1) \approx P_c \times e^{(\frac{\Delta G}{k_B*T})}$, where $k_B$ is Boltzmann's constant, and $P_c$ is the probability of intersystem crossing assuming that $T_1$ and $S_1$ have identical energies within some small error $\epsilon$?

Comment: For small delta-G's the exponential will become linear.

Comment: @KevinKostlan Do you mean this in the sense that it will appear to scale linearly, or that there will be a different phenomena at the limit of small energy gaps?